# not getting data from arraylist

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have arraylists. I want the data from that arraylist. I am not getting the data. instead when i use arraylist.get(i) i get the whole arraylist.

Here is my code

This the main activity where onlick of listview item i am getting the values and passing it to next activity using putStringArrayListExtra.

```
   list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String varr = history.get(position).getLati().toString();
            ArrayList<String>clicklat=new ArrayList<String>();
            clicklat.add(varr);
            String var2 = history.get(position).getLongi().toString();
            ArrayList<String>clicklong=new ArrayList<String>();
            clicklong.add(var2);
            String var3 = history.get(position).getDatetime().toString();
            ArrayList<String>dttime=new ArrayList<String>();
            dttime.add(var3);

            Intent i = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklat", clicklat);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklong", clicklong);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clickdatetime", dttime);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
```

Here is DetailsActivity

```
   public class DetailsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Toolbar toolbar;
String latitudee;
String longitudee;
String dateetime;
ArrayList<String> newLat;
ArrayList<String> newLong;
ArrayList<String> newDateTime;
ArrayList<DetailsPojo> details;
DetailsPojo detailsPojo;
DetailsAdapter adapter;
ListView detList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_details);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    toolbar.setTitle("History Details");
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    details = new ArrayList<DetailsPojo>();
    newLat = new ArrayList<>();
    newLong = new ArrayList<>();
    newDateTime = new ArrayList<>();
    newLat = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("clicklat");
    newLong = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("clicklong");
    newDateTime = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("clickdatetime");
    for (int i = 0; i < newLat.size(); i++) {

        detailsPojo = new DetailsPojo();
        latitudee = newLat.get(i);
        longitudee = newLong.get(i);
        dateetime = newDateTime.get(i);
        Log.e("detais  latitude", "" + latitudee);
        Log.e("detailos  longitudee", "" + longitudee);
        Log.e("detailos  datetimeee", "" + dateetime);
        detailsPojo.setDetailsdatetime(dateetime);
        detailsPojo.setDetailslat(latitudee);
        detailsPojo.setDetailslong(longitudee);

    }
    details.add(detailsPojo);
    detList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.detailsList);
    adapter = new DetailsAdapter(DetailsActivity.this, details);
    detList.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

and this is DetailsAdapter

```
  public class DetailsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context activity;
TextView dt_datetime;
TextView dt_lat;
TextView dt_long;

ArrayList<DetailsPojo> list;
private ArrayList<DetailsPojo> arraylist = null;
public static LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;


public DetailsAdapter(Context a, ArrayList<DetailsPojo> details) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    activity = a;
    list = details;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<DetailsPojo>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(list);

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = convertView;
    if(convertView == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details_item, parent, false);
    }
    final DetailsPojo pojo = list.get(position);
    dt_datetime = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailsdatetime);
    dt_lat = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailslat);
    dt_long = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.detailslong);
    dt_datetime.setText(pojo.getDetailsdatetime());
    dt_lat.setText(pojo.getDetailslat());
    dt_long.setText(pojo.getDetailslong());
    return v;

}

}
```

This is the arraylist

```
 latitude﹕ [21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121776, 21.121774, 21.121774]
```

UPDATE:

this is getLati and getLongi

```
  public List<String> getLati(){
    return this.lat;
}

public List<String> getLongi(){
    return this.longi;
}

public void setLati(List<String> lat){
    this.lat = lat;
}

public void setLongi(List<String> longi){
    this.longi = longi;

}
```

Is there anything wrong? Please help me.

Comment: Why are you creating Arraylist  on Item click? If you have to pass only single item then use just String.

Comment: @Pri you should print the arraylist size. does the arraylist size > 0

Comment: @PhanVănLinh i checked the array list size. it is 1

Comment: @Pri so your listview only display one item

Comment: @PhanVănLinh my list shows the whole arraylist as one item

Comment: @Pri this is your problem right?

Comment: @PhanVănLinh yes this is the problem

Comment: Why you need ListView in detail screen anyway? your passing only one String in each ArrayList in Intent.

Comment: @NullByte How can i do this then

Comment: First tell me what you want to show on DetailScreen? is it map? it seems that way because when you click on History Item, U will show its location on MAP? OR you will show detail address in detail screen..

Comment: @NullByte No i just want to display the list of datetime and latitude longitude

Comment: @Pri Which is you already showing in your History Screen i guess?

Comment: Whatever you doing in MainActivity suppose to get List of history items regarding that MainActivity List item, but your only getting one object from History arraylist.. thats where your problem lies.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91062/discussion-between-pri-and-nullbyte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
            for (int i = 0; i < newLat.size(); i++) {
                DetailsPojo detailsPojo = new DetailsPojo(); //changes here
                latitudee = newLat.get(i);
                longitudee = newLong.get(i);
                dateetime = newDateTime.get(i);
                Log.e("detais  latitude", "" + latitudee);
                Log.e("detailos  longitudee", "" + longitudee);
                Log.e("detailos  datetimeee", "" + dateetime);
                detailsPojo.setDetailsdatetime(dateetime);
                detailsPojo.setDetailslat(latitudee);
                detailsPojo.setDetailslong(longitudee);
                details.add(detailsPojo); // and here
            }
            detList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.detailsList);
            adapter = new DetailsAdapter(DetailsActivity.this, details);
            detList.setAdapter(adapter);
     }
```

I've declared `detailsPojo` object inside the loop instead of a global variable.

**PS**: Make sure `newLong` and  `newDateTime` have the same size as `newLat` to avoid IndexOutOfBoundsException.

---

**UPDATE:**
Change your click listener to:

```
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            ArrayList<String>clicklat= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getLati());

            ArrayList<String>clicklong= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getLongi());

            ArrayList<String>dttime= new ArrayList<String>(history.get(position).getDatetime());

            Intent i = new Intent(HistoryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklat", clicklat);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clicklong", clicklong);
            i.putStringArrayListExtra("clickdatetime", dttime);
            startActivity(i);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you. I see my mistake

Comment: @Rami I got the list view properly but i am getting same data repeated

Comment: @Pri check you adapter data, you sould have a problem there.

Comment: @Rami yes the problem is with adapter.. can u see my another question         http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32862656/listview-displaying-same-data/32864429?noredirect=1#comment53563299_32864429

Answer (score 1):

Try this code in `HereActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < newLat.size(); i++) {
            DetailsPojo detailsPojo = new DetailsPojo();
            latitudee = newLat.get(i);
            longitudee = newLong.get(i);
            dateetime = newDateTime.get(i);
            Log.e("detais  latitude", "" + latitudee);
            Log.e("detailos  longitudee", "" + longitudee);
            Log.e("detailos  datetimeee", "" + dateetime);
            detailsPojo.setDetailsdatetime(dateetime);
            detailsPojo.setDetailslat(latitudee);
            detailsPojo.setDetailslong(longitudee);
            details.add(detailsPojo); // move it to here
        }
      //  details.add(detailsPojo); // remove it
        detList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.detailsList);
        adapter = new DetailsAdapter(DetailsActivity.this, details);
        detList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
....
```

Hope this help

Comment: @Pri I think your code don't have any problem. You put 3 arraylist via Intent (but each array list only have one item, your arraylist have one item because you only add one item to it). Then In `HereActivity` you will get the list with one item -> your listview have one item

Comment: So how can i do this then?

Comment: why your define `clicklat` is the `ArrayList` while it only have one item. What do you want with `clicklat`

Comment: @Pri Yeah, *PhanVănLinh* is right... Post your getLati(), getLongi()... method, you need to change them to return an array of Strings, then you can pass this array via intent.

Comment: @Rami I have added getLati() and getLongi() methods in the question

Comment: An upvote for @PhanVănLinh because he answered a part of the question.

Comment: @Rami thank you. you also help me realize some mistake

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you are creating your lists inside the onClick listener. This means that everytime the user clicks a new List is created and then the value added. So you will always end up with 1 size lists. And if you are trying to use get() on a 1 size list you are getting the only element a.k.a. the whole list. Just move the instructions like:

```
ArrayList<String>clicklat=new ArrayList<String>();
```

outside the listener and you should be ok.

Comment: Are you still getting 1-item lists after this?